My facebook ads account is restricted and request review button is disabled
I logged in to my facebook ads account to see that I'm restricted of ads completely, I never used facebook ads before and don't have any ads on it.
In my account business support page, I see in What you can do buttons two things: request review and view my accounts.
View my accounts direct me to the same page, request review button is disabled and I'm sure I'm opening the account page from the admin(which is the same account that is restricted).
I tried opening this like:
https://www.facebook.com/business-support-home/
Where I can see request review button which is not disabled, it shows me recaptcha which I validate, after that it doesn't do anything at all.
What should I do to lift the restrictions on my account?
